# missing edit links in sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-server, edit-links

I can't find edit links for the top and left menu in shareppoint site!

How to get edit links back?

Any insight, Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your permissions were removed or you're set as a read only user.

Comment: The current user has a full control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs in case of

- You don't have sufficient permission to edit links

**OR**

- Your site template is a publishing site

where `Edit links` (quick launch) is available in Team site and not available to the publishing site.

Meanwhile, if your site is a publishing site , you can manage links by going to

- Site Settings > Look and Feel > Navigation.

Comment: The current user has a full control, how to check the site template

Comment: sorry for late : the easiest way open your site > right click on the page > select view page source> search for "var g_wsaSiteTemplateId" you will find a code, such as "CMSPUBLISHING#0" ,  STS#0 ...etc, if it's "CMSPUBLISHING#0" it's a publishing site ,if it's "STS#0" it's a team site to find out what the template code means you can look at: https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/06/sharepoint-2013-site-template-id-list-for-powershell.html

Answer (score 1):

this ability is not available on all webs. This is because the SharePoint navigation provider limits this function to webs that have been created from a specific list of web templates:

- Team Site – STS#0
- My Site Host – SPSSITEHOST#0
- SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space – SPSPERS#0
- Storage And Social SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space –
  SPSPERS#2
- Storage Only SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space – SPSPERS#3
- Social Only SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space – SPSPERS#4
- Empty SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space – SPSPERS#5
- Project Site – PROJECTSITE#0

[Check this](https://sharepintblog.com/2013/04/26/sharepoint-edit-links-drag-and-drop-navigation-option-missing/)  or [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1384a3dc-7eaf-4ebd-9dfb-93491c6063ad/edit-links-missing-from-site-collection?forum=sharepointadmin)

To check which template is being used, check this one

https://nickhobbs.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/sharepoint-how-to-check-which-site-template-was-used-to-create-a-site-just-using-a-web-browser/

Comment: This isn't true - I have a test site collection that mirrors my production site and both are publishing sites. the test site shows edit links for QL and top, the prod site shows edit links for QL but not top.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a permission problem:
Check if Link **inheritance** is activated. If so the "edit links" button won't show up and you won't be able to edit the links. You can do it on the parent site though.

Answer (score -1):

On the right window there's a section that says "Share", "Follow", and a frame. Click on the frame and links should populate.

Comment: -1 that isn't the case.